# HTML5 video player with multiple audio streams

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, html5-audio, mp4

Is it possible to run mp4 video with multiple audio streams in HTML5 video player and change the streams via button (language select).
I already found a way to check for multiple streams in a video file but the solution works only in **IE** (the property name is AudioTrack). So is this possible to be done in **Chrome** and **Firefox**?

Comment: Yes [HTMLMediaElement.audioTracks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/audioTracks) is the correct way to do it. or... *will be* should I say.  I didn't know IE had support for it, but FF only hides it under a flag (`media.tracks.enabled`), and Chrome has to my knowledge no support at all for the moment...

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Kaiido , I tried your solution and in Firefox and Chrome audioTracks returns only 1 audio track in the video although the tested mp4 file contains 3 streams - 1 video and 2 audio.

Answer (score 0):

Officially not support `AudioTrack` in other browser by following this reference(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/audioTracks)
How about add select button to change video source. And play various video by selected video source.

Comment: This is not a good option because if I have multiple sources this means more storage space. I want to use 1 mp4 file with multiple streams and to be able to select specific stream via button.

Answer (score -2):

I have the exact same problem. [HTMLMediaElement.audioTracks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/audioTracks) seems to be supported only in IE, Edge and Safari. I have tried **Kaiido's** answer suggestions, but still I am getting only one (the default) audio channel of the video file (mp4) in Chrome (with [HTMLMediaElement.CaptureStream()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/captureStream)) and in Mozilla Nightly with configuration change in **media.tracks.enabled** set to true.

Any help will be appreciated, thank you in advance!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20921768)

Comment: I agree that this doesn't answer the question, but what is the point in creating another topic about the same matter.